# Gulp isn't versioning my files anymore. I haven't changed anything, though?

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

Throughout the past two days I've been stuck on this bug with Gulp. I have a Laravel 5 application.

The problem is I keep updating `resources/assets/sass/Dashboard.scss` with new declarations but they don't update in `assets/build/css/`. I can't get rid of `Dashboard-f71e349763.css` because `gulp` won't delete that file and replace it with a new one.

The weirdest part is that I can edit `resources/assets/sass/Authentication.scss` then run `gulp` and everything is perfectly normal as expected.

I've reinstalled `node`, `npm`, `gulp`, and read nearly every GitHub issue out there about this issue and I'm still stuck at square one.

Installed versions of the software involved:

`gulp`:

```
Dolomite: alexander$ gulp -v
[12:57:39] CLI version 3.9.0
[12:57:39] Local version 3.9.0
```

`node`:

```
Dolomite: alexander$ node -v
v5.0.0
```

`npm`:

```
Dolomite: alexander$ npm -v
3.4.1
```

`tree` of the `resources/assets` folder:

```
resources/assets/
├── css
│   ├── Authentication.css
│   ├── Dashboard.css
│   ├── Main.css
│   └── Reset.css
└── sass
    ├── Authentication.scss
    ├── Dashboard.scss
    └── Main.scss
```

`gulpfile.js`:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix
    .sass([
    'Main.scss',
    'Dashboard.scss'
  ], 'resources/assets/css/Dashboard.css')
    .styles([
      'Reset.css',
      'Main.css'
    ], 'public/css/Dashboard.css');

  mix
    .sass([
    'Main.scss',
    'Authentication.scss'
  ], 'resources/assets/css/Authentication.css')
    .styles([
      'Reset.css',
      'Authentication.css'
    ], 'public/css/Authentication.css');

  mix.version([
    'css/Dashboard.css',
    'css/Authentication.css'
  ]);
});
```

`tree` of `public/build/` from the last time it was working:

```
public/build/
├── css
│   ├── Authentication-3f687f1a53.css
│   └── Dashboard-f71e349763.css
└── rev-manifest.json
```

I've ruled out every possible problem (like my Sass being invalid, refreshing the browser without the cache, trying another browser, or other basic and common debug measures of that nature) although the problem seems to be within `gulp` because the Sass is not even making it to `public/css/Dashboard.css`.

If you need more information just let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to edit one of your scss file and save it and then run gulp?

Comment: @alirezasafian That's sort of the entire Gulp workflow. Yes, I have.